# N days before using Time module

Tags: python

Is it possible to determine N days before current time using python Time module not datetime module?

I know datetime module works like this

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

N = 2

date_N_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=N)
```

Comment: so, why would you want to do that without the proper module? It's not like time is included in Python installations, but datetime isn't. Both are standard, and you should use the right tool for the job.

Comment: You could calculate the number of seconds of two days (60*60*24*2) and subtract this from time.time(), but @MarcusMüller is right, you shuldn't do that and use the datetime module.

Comment: @MegaIng NO. **Please** don't do such things. They break. And everytime, bad things happen. See my answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller how does the datetime module consider administrative changes?

Comment: @megaing these are part of the tzinfo database it uses, which is regularly updated. So, if some county in the one US state that allows counties to choose individually decides to abandon daylight saving time, millions of computers (might) need an update. If you're using one of the bigger Linux distros: that's the timezone-data, tzdata or tzinfo package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.

The `time` module simply doesn't concern itself much with calendaring. The question "when was one day ago, exactly" only *sounds* easy, it isn't. Consider things like Daylight Savings Time, or Leap Seconds, or administrative changes, which simply say "24h ago wasn't the same time of day as today, just a day back".

So, use the right tool. `datetime` is included in Python's standard library **exactly** so that people don't build the millionth broken implementation of this.